# What are some ways to secure a directory in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, security, webforms

Just need to secure the directory with possibly a prompt box or something.  Sorry, i am nublariffic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use basic authentication or go all-out with ASP.NET directory security options, depends on what you need. See https://web.archive.org/web/20211020140238/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031204-1.aspx for an overview of options available to you.

To sum it up:

- Windows Authentication Provider for simple authentication, you can use a single username/password combination or integrate with AD if you want to
- Passport Authentication Provider for integration with Microsoft passports
- Forms Authentication Provider gives you the most options but requires the most work, you basically work out all of the authentication parts (the user/password stores and how a user enters his credentials and they are checked in the application).